# How do I partition an area graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following data and the area graph with column2 and column3 is given below. I want to include the first column into the graph by partitioning the graph(using vertical lines probably or different colors) as modela, modelb, modelc. What is the best way to do this?

```
                           Date Manufactured
ModelA      10:05:28 AM 12/14/2011 06:21:05 PM
ModelA      10:06:29 AM 12/15/2011 12:46:21 PM
ModelA      10:07:29 AM 11/12/2011 12:46:21 PM
ModelB      10:10:29 AM 10/10/2011 12:46:21 PM
ModelB      10:11:30 AM 09/14/2011 12:46:21 PM
ModelC      10:12:29 AM 11/11/2011 12:46:21 PM
ModelC      10:14:39 AM 12/14/2011 12:46:21 PM
```

[image: area graph with column 2 and column 3]

Answer (score 0):

Change your series to be models instead of "Date Manufactured". This should give you three colors in the legend on the righthand side, one each for `ModelA`, `ModelB`, and `ModelC`. You can then configure the way the series are displayed.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by "Change your series to models"?. DateManufactured is the chart title.

Comment: If you right click on the blank area on the chart and select `Select data` from the menu, you can define multiple data ranges. These will be graphed together. You might have to have a common set of horizontal  axis labels, though.